# Does OpenSSL function EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(dctx, plaintext+len , &len) converts value of len to 0 after the function call?

Tags: c++, encryption, memory-leaks, openssl, access-violation

I'm using openssl library for encryption and decryption.
I print the value of len variable before and after the function call. so after the function call it shows len value as 0.  code block is as below.
where dctx is  pointer of EVP_CIPHER_CTX type
plaintext is unsigned char pinter
len islength of decrypted text.

```cpp
if (!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(dctx, plaintext+len , &len)) {
    unsigned long err = ERR_get_error();
    char *error_string = ERR_error_string(err?err:EVP_R_BAD_DECRYPT, NULL);
    *errMsg= " Data is Tempered or currupted: " ;
    cout<<"comes here:6 "<<error_string <<"Bad Decryption: data tempered or currupted"<<endl;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(dctx);
    delete[] plaintext;
    return "";
  }else{
    cout<<"clear till 7: "<<endl;
    cout<<" length value in CP9 final  = "<< len<<endl;
  }
```

The strange thing is I'm getting the decrypted text for the fix length but if length varies then program crash with the access violation error as below:

> First chance exception at $009F06ED. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x009f06ed: write of address 0x015d30a4'. Process TestDllProj.exe (892)

I checked all the pointer that I created and released the memory too for the pointer which I allocated.

does the above code block has any issue with that?
please provide solution for this @RemyLebeau and any other solutions too.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. I quickly patched your code to make it compile-able, but this is obviously wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/hv1qK71zM use this link to provide your own MCVE.

Comment: Here is an example generated by ChatGpt: https://godbolt.org/z/7a1e95jGj

Comment: I did use aes 256 gcm mode. where key is 32 byte and IV is 12 byte long.Also if we provide the fix length of text then it working perfectly fine. for example if all the data is 150 length then it would give desirable output. if data length varies then it gave the above mention error of access violation.

Comment: Again provide **M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample. Most probably bug is in code which you didn't show. I can find problem quickly if I could run it.